# Reimporting an entire Git repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

I've imported a repository from GitHub to my Bitbucket account. I haven't touched it for a couple of weeks, and now I want to re-import that same (but now updated) repository from GitHub (and this should be the last time I deal with that GitHub repository. Afterwards I will only work on the Bitbucket project).

Is there a way to import that GitHub repository such that it will override my entire current Bitbucket repository? (I essentially want to start from blank with the newest GitHub files inside my current Bitbucket project.)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can simply fetch all the changes from your github and then do `git push -f --all <bitbucket_remote>`